# 3rd Party cookies error on deployment server

Tags: cookies, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Blazor server app.  I am setting 2 cookies, they work great running from VS, but I deployed it to our dev server and it started throwing errors about not allowing third-party cookies.  It isn't doing any cross-site calls.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?